# Azure Resource Manager Error One or more errors occurred while preparing VM disks

Tags: azure-virtual-machine, azure-resource-manager

I receieve the following error when creating an azure virtual machine using an Azure Resource Manager ARM Template. I am creating 32 datadisks in the template and the following error is logged. The message says

> See disk instance view for details

Where is the disk instance view? I cannot determine how to get additional information about the errors.

Below is the full error message logging in the Azure portal.

statusCode:Conflict
statusMessage:{"status":"Failed","error":{"code":"ResourceDeploymentFailure","message":"The resource operation completed with terminal provisioning state 'Failed'.","details":[{"code":"DiskPreparationError","message":"One or more errors occurred while preparing VM disks. See disk instance view for details."}]}}

Answer (score 5):

Try looking at resources.azure.com; you will navigate to your subscription, then the proper resource group, down to the relevant disk through the Microsoft.Storage provider. You should see an "InstanceView" that will hopefully give more information. This could be the instance view the error is referring to, but there might also be a way to see it through portal. In any case, I find resources.azure.com useful for debugging such errors anyway :).

Answer (score 3):

Nowadays you can go to Resource Groups -> Storage Account -> (Select your type of services) -> And Delete it from there.

I had the same problem, and in order to fix it, I needed to go to the disk that was failing, delete it, and recreate it.

Answer (score 0):

For disk attach issues I have found the detailed information in the portal Overview section for the VM.  Navigate to the VM in the portal, and the overview setion is the default view.

The VM should show as being in a Failed state in the portal. Click on the large red Failed banner on top of the overview section and a panel will open to the right with the error details.

Comment: But I am getting this error even before VM is created.. I am getitng this error when I make custom image out of one of my uploaded VHDs

Comment: Right. I don't know that workflow, but would suggest looking in the resource group for artifacts of the process, and seeing if any of them have errors you can drill into.